# Can not unlock from and lock to Launcher

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, .desktop, dd

I just use `dd -ip /dev/sda -op /dev/sdb` to clone my old disk to new disk, and boot from my new disk.
All the things remain the same except that applications in Launcher changed back to default.
Why? And I cannot unlock from Launcher and lock to Launcher, it sucks, any help?

Comment: Not sure what you exactly did, but launcher icons are defined by `.desktop` files in the `Icon=` -line. These `.desktop` files are stored in `/usr/share/applications` (globally) and/or in `~/.local/share/applications` (locally). If they exist in both (for the same application), the local ones overrule the global ones.

Comment: Sorry maybe I mislead you, "icon" I just mean "application", not the icon picture

Comment: You cloned your hdd with the dd command and now have only the copy plugged in. And there you have not your custom launcher applications, but the default ones of a fresh install. Did I understand you right so far? What was your partitioning setup (separate partitions for `/home` or other directories, or just `/` and `swap`)?

Comment: @ByteCommander yeah.exactly. And I have home directory as a separated partition

Comment: And the partitions are all recognized and mounted correctly (`sudo parted -l`)? Or maybe it lost somehow the link to the /home partition (maybe different UUID does not match the one in /etc/fstab - don't know how a dd-clone would look like according to this)

Comment: Actually, i can get access to my /home directly without problem. Are all files in ~/.local/share/applications will show in the launcher?

Comment: Actually, what i want to know is that, how does ubuntu determine what to show on the Launcher? Not all of files in `/usr/share/applications` will show on the Launcher right?

Comment: Sorry, i forget to mention, i cannot lock anything to Launcher and cannot unlock anything from Launcher either, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that answer. But to be more helpfule, i will show you how to debug it.

1. Since it's something related to Launcher, And i don't know how does Launcher work, so i just need to find something related to Launcher. Which is `Appearance` in Dash.(I found this by Google).
2. Under `Behavior` tab, I can't change everything, i can click the checkbox, but nothing happen.
3. So, now i think there should be some output information in terminal. So i need to know how to open `Appearance` in terminal
4. Found `Appearance` in `/usr/share/applications`, the command is `unity-control-center appearance`
5. Type `unity-control-center appearance` in Terminal. And do the same thing as step 2. Terminal show output like this:

> dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes
>   toconf:GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._g_2dfile_2derror_2dquark.Code17:
>   Cannot open dconf database: invalid gvdb header
>
> Of course i don't know what the hell it is. But i now get some new key word to search on the Google! Yeah! I searched `Cannot open dconf database: invalid gvdb header`
>
> And I found solution, **just remove `~/.config/dconf/`** (Of course backup first)