# How to manually add an application to favorites in 17.10?

Tags: icons, 17.10

I am trying to pin an application to the 'launcher'. In Ubuntu 17.10 it is called 'add to favorites'.

With most applications it works by:

1. Launch the application
2. Right-click its icon on the launcher
3. Add to favorites

However, for some applications, the "Add to favorites" choice is not there:

[image]

I tried following the solution from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/586166/64420) but failed, probably because 17.10 uses a new desktop (whatever that means).

Is there some way to add an application to the 'launcher' manually?

Comment: You can manually drag the application to the dock when it's not running.

Comment: @muru Thank you, but this doesn't work for me, since the application is not in this thingy that used to be dash. Also, dragging and dropping the binary executable to the dock did not work.

Comment: Oh, then you'd probably need to write a `.desktop` file for it as given in https://askubuntu.com/q/967409/158442

Comment: @muru Thank you! That works, but I only have a generic icon on the launcher and when I click it an *additional* icon with the green robot appears. However this is a minor detail.

Comment: Hmm, maybe setting the `Icon` field may help, not sure though.

Comment: @MartinDrozdik See if this trick gets rid of multiple icons: https://askubuntu.com/a/971431/480481