# Few application icons not appearing in Ubuntu Dock after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, icons, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, terminator

After upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10, Ubuntu Dock icons of some of my apps are not appearing. They appear properly in the dash. I verified the `*.desktop` files for the applications in `/usr/share/applications` and `~/.local/share/applications`.

E.g. dock icon is not displaying for "Terminator". Check out the attached image.

[image]

This is how the icon for the same application appears in dash search:

[image]

Content of `/usr/share/applications/terminator.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Terminator
Comment=Multiple terminals in one window
TryExec=terminator
Exec=terminator
Icon=terminator
Type=Application
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;TerminalEmulator;System;
StartupNotify=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=terminator
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow;
Keywords=terminal;shell;prompt;command;commandline;
[NewWindow Shortcut Group]
Name=Open a New Window
Exec=terminator
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Any pointers to debug this issue will be helpful.

Comment: Did you tried reinstalling Terminator?

Comment: @lapisdecor I did try reinstalling terminator. doesn't help.

Comment: Removing the icon from the laucher and using add to favorites from the dash doesn't solve it?

Comment: @lapisdecor that helps! there is an issue though. I've configured Ctrl + Alt + T to open terminator instead of gnome-terminal. Even if I "Add To Favorites", a new terminator app is launched on Ctrl + Alt + T with the wrong icon.

Comment: I can have a workaround for it by keeping "terminator" as a startup application. After all, I would always require a terminal. That is just a hack and doesn't solve the internal problem though.

Answer (score 8):

<sub>Try this method in an Xorg session, not sure whether it would work in a Wayland session.</sub>

1. Launch one such application, say Terminator, whose correct icon is not seen in Ubuntu Dock.
2. Run `xprop WM_CLASS` in Terminal. The cursor should turn into a crosshair.
3. Place the crosshair over Terminator and click. You should get a `WM_CLASS` string for Terminator.
4. Open Terminator's `.desktop` file and add the following line

   ```
   StartupWMClass=OBTAINED-VALUE
   ```

   In place of `OBTAINED-VALUE` put a value you got from step 3 without any quotes.
5. Save the `.desktop` file.

Comment: I think it might work in Wayland too, at least for apps running under XWayland.

Comment: Adding StartupWMClass using the method you told doesn't fix the issue in the Wayland session(default on 17.10). In fact, StartupWMClass is not even required for an Xorg session. The icons work fine on Xorg session without this fix. The issue is with Wayland session then.

Comment: I had this issue in both sessions, wayland and xorg. But @pomsky 's instruction solved the problem for both sessions.

Comment: The problem is that the curson only turns into a crosshair in the desktop, if i place it on any window it will change back in to the normal cursor, not letting me see the class.

Comment: @Maxrunner Should not be "*any*" window, only apps running under Wayland instead of XWayland (Hint: try with Firefox, it should work). To get it work with all windows,switch back to Xorg session from the default Wayland session.