# Third party application Icon not displaying in dock for Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 17.10, .desktop, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I created an executable `.desktop` file in my Desktop which should launch a GUI application along with displaying an icon in dock, but in Ubuntu 17.10 icon is not displaying in dock:

[image: desktop with download dialog]

In previous Ubuntu versions (14.04 to 17.04) I didn't face this issue.

In Ubuntu 17.10 no 3rd party applications with icons as executables are being launched by default, It's asking for trust and launch to proceed.

[image: untrusted application dialog]

How can I give the launchers default execute permission, or whatever permission is needed to avoid getting this dialog?

The executable was created by compiling in Ubuntu 14.04 to support backward compatibility.

The `.desktop` file created to display the icon contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/env/ xdg-open 
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=MDM
Comment=MAVLDM
Terminal=false
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=example-content
MimeType=text/html;text/xml;application/xhtml+xml;application/xml;application/vnd.mozilla.xul+xml;application/rss+xml;application/rdf+xml;image/gif;image/jpeg;image/png;x-scheme-handler/http;x-scheme-handler/https;x-scheme-handler/ftp;x-scheme-handler/chrome;
StartupNotify=false
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.20
Path=/home/ravi/Downloads/MDM
Exec=/home/ravi/Downloads/MDM/MAVLDM
Icon=/home/ravi/Downloads/MDM/mavldm.png
```

Is this changed in Ubuntu 17.10?

Comment: @pomsky workaround you suggested for that issue is not working for me even in Xorg session

Comment: Please check two things first: 1. Does the icon file specified in the desktop file (i.e. `/home/ravi/Downloads/MDM/mavldm.png`) exist? If yes, 2. Click on "Activities" and search for "MDM". Does it show the icon?

Comment: 1. Icon file specified is present 2. I clicked on Activities and searched for mavldm.png, i am seeing nothing. Same scenario i repeated in Ubuntu 16.04, i can see the icon in activities

Comment: My use case is not to make it as favorites, after clicking on the executable icon should come in the dock directly launching a GUI application. It's is working in previous Ubuntu versions

Comment: It is having executable permissions. Executable is working fine as expected but only icon is not displaying

Answer (score 2):

First right click on the `.desktop` file and select *Properties*. Then go to *Permissions* tab and check the "*Allow executing file as program*" if it's unchecked. Alternatively you may run

```
 chmod +x <filename.desktop>
```

Then double-click on the `.desktop` file, a window with the heading "*Untrusted application launcher*" should pop up (as in your [second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyFCy.png)). Click on the "*Trust and Launch*" button. The `.desktop` file should be fixed now (i.e. should show correct name and icon specified inside the file) and the application will be launched.

From next time on it won't ask for any permission and launch the application straight away.

Comment: If this doesn't work try adding a `StartupWMClass=` line to the `.desktop` file following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/971431/480481).

Comment: Is there any option to bypass the **Untrusted application launcher** through terminal commands and launch the application even for the first time. As it is showing like a text file,till we click on "trust and launch".